# load random word from 2 arrays and combine them in a single click

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

okay so I am trying to make a single call to load 1 word from 2 different arrays in javascript

so the end result would be "round bubble" or "aromatic things"

this is what I have

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
             function getDesc() {
             var descr = new Array["straight", "round", "aromatic");                          
             var randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random()* descr.length)         
             }
             function getNoun() {
             var nouns = new Array("bubble", "office", "things");
             var randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random()* nouns.length)         
             }

   function getWords() {
     getDesc();
     getNoun();
}
    </script>


       <div id="myBox">
       Words load here
       </div>

       <P>
         <a href="javascript:getWords()">Button</a>
       </p>
```

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation or just want a chunk of copy-pastable working code?

Comment: And what have you tried?  You just have two functions being called in another function

Comment: If someone could tell me were I went wrong.  Yes please explain it to me I am trying to learn.  I know i need to pull a random word from each array and I have had it working were I can pull from one or the other but I am trying to pull one from each.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since you've asked for an explanation, here's one:

Functions are your servants. You tell them what to do and usually want them to return and to bring you something. Your functions are not particularly skilled ones, because they do their hard work, but never return and never bring what you've asked for. To make them of more use to you, equip them with `return` statements:

```
     function getDesc() {
         var descr = ["straight", "round", "aromatic"];                          
         var randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * descr.length);
         return descr[randomChoice]; 
     }
```

(this can be written more concisely, but that's not the point for now).

Now, when your functions actually produce results, you can assign these results to variables and manipulate them, for example:

```
   function getWords() {
     var desc = getDesc();
     var noun = getNoun();
     var phrase = desc + " " + noun;
     return phrase;
 }
```

Again, since `getWords` is a function, it has to return something.

The final part is to display what `getWords` returned. There are many ways to do that, from simple

```
  alert(getWords())
```

to more involved

```
  document.getElementById('someID').innerHTML = getWords()
```

I leave an exact implementation as an exercise. Hope that helped!

Comment: thanks for this I understand better now and will post once i get it up and running.